# Strcmp for two dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Lets say I have an two dimensional array containing a list of 3 different words. I am trying to check if a predefined word is equal to any of the words in the list. What would be the format of the strcmp function?

Example:

```
char message[5] = {"hello"};

char keywords[3][10] = {"dolphin", 
                        "rhino",
                        "hello" };

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    if(strcmp(message, keywords[i][0]) == 0) {
      printf("Match Found!");
      break;
    }
    else
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `strcmp` to

```
strcmp(message, keywords[i])
```

String compare function need two string. `keywords[i][0]` is a first character of string. So you are comparing string with character.

gcc compiler used to give warning as

> /usr/include/string.h:143:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’

Code:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
char message[5] = {"hello"};
char keywords[3][10] = {"dolphin", 
                        "rhino",
                        "hello" };

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        printf("Check 1 : %c\n", keywords[i][0]);
        printf("check 2 : %s\n", keywords[i]);
        //printf("%s\n", keywords[i][0]);// try this you will get error
        if(strcmp(message, keywords[i]) == 0) {
            printf("Match Found!\n");
            break;
        }
        else
            break;
     }
 }

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Check 1 : d
check 2 : dolphin
Check 1 : r
check 2 : rhino
Check 1 : h
check 2 : hello
Match Found!
```

Answer (score 2):

The `keywords[3][10]` means an array of `3` strings each of max length `10`.

Therefore, you are accessing the string wrong way:

When you write `keyword[i][0]` it means `0`th character of `i`th string.
However, what you need is only `i`th string, you need not dereference it second time, i.e. you should use:

`if(strcmp(message, keywords[i]) == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

In this way ,you can compare two string .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
  int main(){
    char message[6] = {"rhino"};
    char keywords[3][10] = {"dolphin", 
                             "rhino",
                             "hello" };

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
           for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

               if(strcmp(message, keywords[i]) == 0) {
                        printf("Match Found!");
               printf("\n %s Match with %s",message, keywords[i]);
                        break;
               }
              else
                 break;
        }
      }
     getch();
     return 0;
}
```

Let me know ,if anything goes wrong!!!

Answer (score 0):

change your strcmp function to

```
 for(i=0;i<=5;i++)
      {
          if(strcmp(&keybord[i][0],message))
      }
```

and enjoy :)